# Aurelia TypeError: this.sourceExpression.connect is not a function

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-templating

I have encountered runtime error:

> TypeError: this.sourceExpression.connect is not a function

Problem is that stacktrace does not show anything useful, it points (randomly) to the last line of one of bundled components (in this case Leaflet's MarkerClusterGroup):

> Uncaught TypeError: this.sourceExpression.connect is not a function
>       at ChildInterpolationBinding.connect (MarkerClusterGroup.Refresh.js:110)
>       at enqueueBindingConnect (MarkerClusterGroup.Refresh.js:110)
>       at ChildInterpolationBinding.bind (MarkerClusterGroup.Refresh.js:110)
>       at View.bind (MarkerClusterGroup.Refresh.js:110)
>       at If._show (MarkerClusterGroup.Refresh.js:110)
>       at If._update (MarkerClusterGroup.Refresh.js:110)
>       at If.conditionChanged (MarkerClusterGroup.Refresh.js:110)
>       at BehaviorPropertyObserver.selfSubscriber (MarkerClusterGroup.Refresh.js:110)
>       at BehaviorPropertyObserver.call (MarkerClusterGroup.Refresh.js:110)
>       at BehaviorPropertyObserver.setValue (MarkerClusterGroup.Refresh.js:110)
>       at If.descriptor.set [as condition] (MarkerClusterGroup.Refresh.js:110)
>       at Object.setValue (MarkerClusterGroup.Refresh.js:110)
>       at Binding.updateTarget (MarkerClusterGroup.Refresh.js:110)
>       at Binding.call (MarkerClusterGroup.Refresh.js:110)
>       at BehaviorPropertyObserver.callSubscribers (MarkerClusterGroup.Refresh.js:110)
>       at BehaviorPropertyObserver.call (MarkerClusterGroup.Refresh.js:110)

Answer (score 1):

Cause of the issue was not related with file where stack trace was pointing to. Issue was syntax error (double dot: **dto..firstName**) in binding expression in one of Aurelia templates, something like:

```
<input value.bind="dto..firstName" />
```

Template had no relation or dependency to line of code (or even JS library) where stack trace was pointing to.

Comment: I'd recommend filing a GitHub issue to get a discussion started on improving error messages like this.

Comment: With my changes in `aurelia-binding` 2.0.0, that binding expression will throw a parser error "unexpected token .". Would that be helpful enough?

Comment: @AshleyGrant, yes, I think GitHub is good idea. This entry is more for reference. Do you know Aurelia project in which the issue should be filled in?

Comment: @FredKleuver I think showing the value of unexpected token would be helpful, so it's easier to figure where it originates from.

Comment: It does, but it's a period which is not particularly visible next to quotes in a comment :) For you it would say: `Parser Error: Unexpected token . at column 4 in expression [dto..firstName]`. You can try it out if you install aurelia-binding 2.0.0

Comment: @FredKleuver I installed aurelia-binding 2.0.0 and I am getting exactly the same error and stacktrace. I also double-checked if 2.0.0 is in the bundle, it has lines from last pull request from you (ex this line `this.currentToken = T$EOF`). Also, I tried with both bundled template and one that is downloaded from server. Maybe I should file issue in aurelia-binding repository then?

Comment: Yes, go ahead. Seems that I overlooked this specific case. I've reproduced this in a unit test.